# How do I speed up Hibernate merge()?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

currently I have an object that looks something like this (with other member variables as well):

```
public class Parent {
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<Child>;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST,
        CascadeType.MERGE }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }
    public setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }
}
```

the Child class then also has references to its own children, as well as its Parent object. Each of its children also has a reference back to its owning Child object.

I realize this is a lot of circular references, but at this point it's not really viable to change the models :(

For persistence, I have something like the following:

```
private void persist(List<Parent> parents) {
    synchronized(parentDAO) {
         parentDao.startTx();
    try {
        for ( Parent parent : parents ) {
             parentDao.merge( parent );
    } catch (Exception e) {
         parentDao.rollback();
    }
    parentDao.commit();
```

}

the parentDao essentially just wraps different entity Manager functions (i.e. parentDao.startTx() gets calls EntityManager.getTransaction().begin() , parentDao.merge() calls EntityManager.merge() , etc ).

I'm trying to merge a Parent that has a Set of size 11,000+. The merge takes over 7 hours, and I need to cut it down as much as possible, since I have a large number of database operations that need to be run overnight, and this one call is taking up a majority of my allotted time.

What are my options to speed up this operation? I know that cutting down the units of work by breaking up Set into smaller sets ( my coworker suggested 100 Child objects at once ) and calling parentDao.merge(Set ) is one option, but would that actually speed up the entire operation? ARe there any other ways of speeding up this operation? Any manual operations like generating db dumps and running scripts are out of the question, since this process is supposed to run weekly on a bunch of different environments.

We use Oracle for our database, and we're on Hibernate 3.6.6.

Thanks!!

Comment: Use plain old JDBC...

Comment: Have your turned on tracing for hibernate to see what the executed SQL looks like?  They can be very inefficient.  11K records seems like a trivial amount of data.  Another reason to not use an ORM.

Comment: @OldProgrammer I have, but we have an incredibly complicated object tree ( what I've described doesnt really illustrate how complicated it is) with 4-5 layers of parent-child relationships, with circular references between some of the layers.. so the generated SQL is impossible to deconstruct ( it doesnt help that hibernate logging in log4j doesn't print out the actual inserted values :( )

Comment: Sorry.  BTW, there is a logging option to dump bound parameter values from a hibernate query.  I forget the exact process, but you can search for it.

Comment: @OldProgrammer oh right, I've actually set that up before, thanks for the reminder :)